# Find the Missing Months

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got my own way of doing this but I'm not convinced its the best, in **C#**

Given a `List<DateTime>`, a `DateTime startDate` and an `DateTime endDate`. How would you return a new  `List<DateTime>`for every **month** between `startDate` and `endDate` that is **not** included within the original `List<DateTime>` inclusive of the `startDate` and `endDate`.

Dates are not guarnteed to be the start of the month, could be any date within the month.

`startDate` and `endDate` could span multiple years.

The returned list should contain the first day of every month that is missing.

Thanks, and I hope it makes sense.

Comment: When you say "month", does it include the year? Are January 2010 and January 2011 different months in your description ?

Comment: can you give an example if possible?

Comment: If you specify a startDate as the 15th of january, should you include january? Since you specify you want the 1st of that month that is.

Comment: Oh, what a lovely bikeshed we've painted :)

Comment: @Lasse yes you should include january

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = new List<DateTime>
    {
        new DateTime(1231223423433132),
        new DateTime(13223123132),
        new DateTime(12333123132),
        new DateTime(123345123132),
        DateTime.Now,
        new DateTime(5634534553)
    };

var allYearMonthes = list.Select(o => 
                             Eumerable.Range(1, 12)
                                 .Select(q => new { o.Year, Month = q }))
                          .SelectMany(o => o);

var enumerable = allYearMonthes.Except(list.Select(o => new { o.Year, o.Month }));

var dateTimes = enumerable.Select(o => new DateTime(o.Year, o.Month, 1));
```

**EDIT:**
for those who interested in probably complete solution:

```
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now, EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(5).AddMonths(2);
var allYearMonthes = Enumerable.Range(StartDate.Year, EndDate.Year - StartDate.Year -1)
                               .Select(o => Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
                               .Select(q => new { Year = o, Month = q }))
                               .SelectMany(o => o);

var enumerable = allYearMonthes.Except(list.Select(o => new { o.Year, o.Month }));
var dateTimes = enumerable.Select(o => new DateTime(o.Year, o.Month, 1));
```

Comment: your code was including all months in the year bellow start data.  For instance if you have start date 5/1/2010 than your code would include 1/1/2010, 2/1/2010, 3/1/2010, 4/1/2010.  Same story for end date.  I changed slightly your code to provide only dates between start data and end date.  I gave you +1.

Comment: Yes I missed that but it's a trivial task to filter the dates to include only dates between start and end date, I miss some the details of question but the solution could be easily adopted, and you're completely right :-)

Comment: This won't work if your data set contains a year long gap. It only produces output for years where there is an item in the input for that year. Consider the case where the input is empty, or the case where the start date occurs in the year before the first date in the list.

Comment: Yes, but simply you can use a `Enumerable.Range(startDate.Year, EndDate.Year - StartDate.Year +1)` to generate the years, I just want to present the idea

Comment: @Jani... looking good but your code is years - 1... I'm guessing that should be + 1?

Comment: I don't know, change it to what you want, logic part of my brains sucks dude :-)

Comment: Gone with this answer, purely because its easy to understand... ish ;)

Comment: The code only takes `StartDate.Year` and `EndDate.Year` into account, so Vlad's comment is still valid. For example if `StartDate = EndDate = DateTime.Now` and the given date list is empty, all of this year's months will be returned (instead of the current month only).

Comment: LINQ is just a fancy way to write for loops. I'm not sure that using it at the expense of readability is really a good route to take. I mean, it's fun and all... but ultimately this method would result in a lot of extra calls and some inefficiencies in comparision to simply writing a couple of for loops (one to create all of the months, and the other to compare them) and calling it a day.

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming the same month in different years is considered different:

```
    private List<DateTime> GetUnincludedMonths(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate,
                                               IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
    {
        var allMonths = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>(); //month, year
        DateTime date = startDate;
        while (date <= endDate)
        {
            allMonths.Add(Tuple.Create(date.Month, date.Year));
            date = date.AddMonths(1);
        }
        allMonths.Add(Tuple.Create(endDate.Month, endDate.Year));

        allMonths.ExceptWith(dates.Select(dt => Tuple.Create(dt.Month, dt.Year)));
        return allMonths.Select(t => new DateTime(t.Item2, t.Item1, 1)).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: This misses the last month if the endDate has a lower day-value than the startDate, ie. 15. january to 1. february, you add a month, and get to 15. of february, which is above the endDate.

Comment: Like the answer but unfortunately I can't use 4.0 so don't have access to tuple

Comment: @mjmcloug So use a `KeyValuePair`

Comment: @mjmcloug - Like Jani suggested you could use a KeyValuePair (You could also introduce a simple `MonthYear` class with two int properties for the month and year - however if you do - remember to implelent `Equls` and `GetHashCode` !)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMissingMonths(IEnumerable<DateTime> currentDates, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var yearMonths = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>(currentDates.Select(d => Tuple.Create(d.Year, d.Month)));
    DateTime current = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1);
    if (current < startDate)
        current = current.AddMonths(1);
    while (current <= endDate)
    {
        if (!yearMonths.Contains(Tuple.Create(current.Year, current.Month)))
        {
            yield return current;
        }
        current = current.AddMonths(1);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: if you can't use Tuple, you can use an anonymous type instead, with a helper method to create the HashSet:

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMissingMonths(IEnumerable<DateTime> currentDates, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var yearMonths = MakeHashSet(currentDates.Select(d => new { d.Year, d.Month }));
    DateTime current = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1);
    if (current < startDate)
        current = current.AddMonths(1);
    while (current <= endDate)
    {
        if (!yearMonths.Contains(new { current.Year, current.Month }))
        {
            yield return current;
        }
        current = current.AddMonths(1);
    }
}

static HashSet<T> MakeHashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(source);
}
```

The `MakeHashSet` method allows you to use type inference to create a `HashSet<T>` when T is an anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

[LINQPad](http://linqpad)-working solution:

```
void Main()
{
    var dates = new List<DateTime>
    {
        new DateTime(2011, 1, 1),
        new DateTime(2011, 3, 5),
        new DateTime(2011, 7, 28),
    };
    var startDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
    var endDate = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31);
    var existingMonths =
        (from dt in dates
         select dt.Year * 12 + dt.Month - 1).Distinct().ToArray();
    var missingMonths =
        from ym in Enumerable.Range(
            startDate.Year * 12 + startDate.Month - 1,
            (endDate.Year * 12 + endDate.Month) - (startDate.Year * 12 + startDate.Month) + 1)
        where !existingMonths.Contains(ym)
        select new DateTime(ym / 12, ym % 12 + 1, 1);
    missingMonths.Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMissingMonths(
  DateTime startDate,
  DateTime endDate,
  IEnumerable<DateTime> source)
{
  IEnumerable<DateTime> sourceMonths =
    source.Select(x => new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, 1))
          .ToList()
          .Distinct();
  return MonthsBetweenInclusive(startDate, endDate).Except(sourceMonths);
}

public IEnumerable<DateTime> MonthsBetweenInclusive(
  DateTime startDate,
  DateTime endDate)
{
  DateTime currentMonth = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1);
  DateTime endMonth = new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, 1);

  while(currentMonth <= endMonth)
  {
    yield return currentMonth;
    currentMonth = currentMonth.AddMonths(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "AllMonths"? And won't AllMonths have to return a collection of DateTime in order to fit the return type of the GetMissingMonths method? And won't thus .Except not work since you're selecting out only the month?

Comment: Whoops, renamed a method and didn't fix the call. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var days = (new string[] { "3/23/2000", "7/3/2004", "1/3/2004", "3/1/2011" })
                        .Select(a => Convert.ToDateTime(a));

            days = days.Select(a => a.AddDays(1 - (a.Day))).Distinct();
            days = days.OrderBy(a => a);

            var missingMonths = GetMissingMonths(days).ToList();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMissingMonths(IEnumerable<DateTime> days)
        {
            DateTime previous = days.First();
            foreach (var current in days.Skip(1))
            {
                int months = (current.Month - previous.Month) + 
                                    12 * (current.Year - previous.Year);
                for (int i = 1; i < months; i++)
                {
                    yield return previous.AddMonths(i);
                }
                previous = current;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jani +1 for his idea.  This one is one line of code :)

```
void Main()
 {

 var list = new List<DateTime>
 {
  new DateTime(2005, 10, 11),
  new DateTime(2009, 3, 4),
  new DateTime(2010, 5, 8),
  new DateTime(2010, 8, 10),
  DateTime.Now,
  new DateTime(2010, 4, 8)
 };

        var result= Enumerable.Range(list.Min (l => l.Year), list.Max (l => l.Year) - list.Min (l => l.Year)).
             SelectMany (e => Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select (en => new DateTime(e, en, 1))).
             Except(list.Select(o => new DateTime(o.Year, o.Month, 1))).
             Where (o => o.Date > list.Min (l => l.Date) && o.Date < list.Max (l => new DateTime(l.Year, l.Month, 1)));

    }
```

Comment: @Iain. Thanks for pointing out.  I fixed it.  Check this out.

Comment: Has the problem if being nearly unreadable, thus harder to maintain. Cool that it's one line though.

Comment: @blesh.  Agree that it is hard to read, but it shows power of LINQ.

Comment: Haha.. it's okay, it's not much harder to look at than the chosen answer. ironically, LINQ is just fancy way to write loops in a more functional manner. I'm not sure it's worth leveraging at the cost of maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my hat in, because it's fun. and I didn't see anyone putting a DateTime in a regular for loop, which I never get to do, so again... fun.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> FindMissingMonths(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, IEnumerable<DateTime> inputs)
{
    var allMonths = new List<DateTime>();
    for (DateTime d = startDate; d < endDate; d = d.AddMonths(1))
    {
        allMonths.Add(new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1));
    }
    var usedMonths = (from d in inputs
                        select new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1)).Distinct();
    return allMonths.Except(usedMonths);
}
```

fixed a bug, tested, works.

Comment: Not that different from my way... I like it though.. complex linq can sometimes make things hard to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public IList<DateTime> GetMissingMonths(IList<DateTime> currentList, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        // Create a list for the missing months
        IList<DateTime> missingList = new List<DateTime>();

        // Select a startdate
        DateTime testingDate = startDate;

        // Begin by the month of startDate and ends with the month of endDate
        // month of startDate and endDate included
        while(testingDate <= endDate)
        {
            if (currentList.Count(m => m.Month == testingDate.Month && m.Year == testingDate.Year) == 0)
            {
                missingList.Add(new DateTime(testingDate.Year, testingDate.Month, 1));
            }
            testingDate = testingDate.AddMonths(1);
        }
        return missingList;
    }
```

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain so that everyone can learn from your findings